# Is it considered bad architecture to have a downstream service access write APIs in an upstream service?

Tags: rest, service

I have a boss that is gung ho about only having downstream services consume data from an upstream service.  However, we have situations where it would make sense to have the downstream service send an update to the upstream service, which naturally he is completely against.

So my question is is it bad architecture to have a downstream services send update data to an upstream service?

Seems like RESTful apis would be horrible architecture on an if that is the case, considering an upstream service would never have the need for a PUT, only GETs.

Is he wrong, or what am I missing?

Comment: what sort of update would the downstream service need to propagate to the upstream service?

Comment: It would be a user creation.  The downstream service would import a list of users to be stored on there system, also including data specific to there system, then ping an Identity server to create the specified users. Identity server would ignore users that already exist based on email address, or username, or other unique identitfiers.

Comment: The option he is looking for is to import the users on identity server, containing the clients specific data, then ping the client with the user id and the additional data to update there system.  The issue I have with this is Identity Server will be handling multiple clients and mainting import data for multple clients would be daunting.  Also, asking Identity server to handle import data for a third party system seems wrong.   Personally I think it should be a two step process, import the users on identity, then import the additional data on the client.  But my boss is agaisnt that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a job for messaging. I've built a few of these integrations where systems broadcast changes in their environment to a message broker and anything that's interested in that change consumes the message and acts accordingly. A shared message format is required though.

If Upstream service is A and Downstream service is B, then

B accepts a new user ingest. B processes the request and creates a new user. B then creates the message, for example:

```
<user mode="new">
  <name></name>
  <email></email>
</user>
```

or

```
<users>
  <user mode="new">
    <name></name>
    <email></email>
  </user>
<users>
```

and sends it to a topic at the message broker, e.g. [Apache ActiveMQ](https://activemq.apache.org/). The topic could be:

```
/user
```

A can either be a durable subscriber to the `user` topic or you can use [Apache Camel](https://camel.apache.org/) to route the message to another topic which A would subscribe to. Persistent messages and durable topic consumers ensure messages aren't lost if the broker goes down, in theory.

A sees the `user` message, sees the `mode` is `new` and examines the `email` to see if it needs to create the user. A then processes the message and does what it needs to do.

At this point, if there are other systems that would need to know about the new user A can broadcast the message to another topic which they listen to. You would do that if A needs to know about a new user first and then decide who else needs to know. If they all need to know, then they can all subscribe to the `user` topic.

Using messaging, no system needs to know about any other system. Each system just broadcasts events in a known format (in this case a domain specific `XML` message but `JSON` is fine).

If you have multiple clients, each can do their own ingest then broadcast an appropriate message or messages, perhaps one per user even, to the topic and all the other systems can act on it.

If you don't want to use `XML` or `JSON` you could attach a `CSV` of all new users to the message. The key is, all other systems should know what the message format is.

Comment: I get all that.  My question is whether doing this is bad architecture, considering A is upstream from B.